# Can I charge a fee on top of the merchant payout with balanced orders

Tags: balanced-payments

I'm updating my code to use balanced api 1.1 and I'm interested in the new Orders construct. Everything looks pretty good about it, since our orders are only associated with one merchant customer. We charge an inclusive fee on the order and don't want to make 2 charges to the customer, which leads to my question:

If I create a single order, with one buyer, one seller, and one debit, can I credit both the seller's account, and my business account?

In other words, after debiting the buyer the full amount (let's say $100) and crediting the seller with their portion (let's say $95) will the remaining $5 be 'stuck' or will I be able to transfer that into the business's account (my business)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an Order can technically have two merchants associated to it. The one specified when you create it and the `owner_customer` from your marketplace.

The documentation appears to be lacking anything referring to this so I've created a Github issue to track documenting [how to collect fees with Orders](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-docs/issues/418)!